# SQL Server Distributed queries with Teradata

Tags: sql-server, odbc, oledb, teradata, linked-server

I am trying to get distributed queries to run on SQL Server 2012 with a linked server to Teradata.

Connection works fine and query returns quickly if I pass the where clause into the remote SQL using `openquery` e.g.

```
select * 
from openquery(td, 'select * from lib.purchases where z_PO = ''123456''')
```

However the below does not run as expected: SQL Server loads the entire table and performs a local filter:

```
select * 
from openquery(td, 'select * from lib.purchases') where z_PO = '123456'
```

The source table has 100M records.

Obviously index play no role here as query runs just fine on TD side.

What I have tried:

1. `sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 1`
2. set `Collation Compatible" = True` on the linked server properties
3. Instead of 2, set `Collation Name = Latin1_BIN` to match (closely?) TD character set (ASCII).

Not sure collation is the issue as I get same result when filtering on numeric fields.

Somehow the so-called query optimizer in SQL Server does not push simple filtering down to the remote server.

Is this the ODBC driver's fault (using 16.10) - a setting, a bug? SQL Server 2012 (v11.0.6248.0) setting I am missing (or path req'd)?

Below is the OLEDB for ODBC properties that I capture in SQL Profiler:

```
<ProviderInformation>
<Provider>MSDASQL</Provider>
<LinkedServer>td</LinkedServer>
<ProviderCapabilitiesAndSettings>
    <Ansi92EntrySupport>0</Ansi92EntrySupport>
    <ODBCCoreSupport>1</ODBCCoreSupport>
    <ODBCMinimumSupport>1</ODBCMinimumSupport>
    <SimpleGrammarSupport>0</SimpleGrammarSupport>
    <AnsiLikeSupport>0</AnsiLikeSupport>
    <SQLLikeSupport>1</SQLLikeSupport>
    <DateLiteralsSupport>0</DateLiteralsSupport>
    <GroupBySupport>0</GroupBySupport>
    <InnerJoinSupport>0</InnerJoinSupport>
    <SubqueriesSupport>0</SubqueriesSupport>
    <SimpleUpdatesSupport>0</SimpleUpdatesSupport>
    <HistogramsSupport>0</HistogramsSupport>
    <ColumnLevelCollationSupport>0</ColumnLevelCollationSupport>
    <ConnectionSharingSupport>0</ConnectionSharingSupport>
    <MultipleActiveRowsetsSupport>0</MultipleActiveRowsetsSupport>
    <MultipleResultsSupport>1</MultipleResultsSupport>
    <AllowLimitingRowsReturned>1</AllowLimitingRowsReturned>
    <NullConcatenationYieldsNull>0</NullConcatenationYieldsNull>
    <StructuredStorageAccessToLargeObjects>1</StructuredStorageAccessToLargeObjects>
    <MultipleConcurrentLargeObjectSupport>0</MultipleConcurrentLargeObjectSupport>
    <DynamicParametersSupport>1</DynamicParametersSupport>
    <NestedQueriesSupport>1</NestedQueriesSupport>
    <IndicesAvailableAsAccessPath>0</IndicesAvailableAsAccessPath>
    <AllowDataAccessByReference>1</AllowDataAccessByReference>
    <RowsetChangesAreVisible>0</RowsetChangesAreVisible>
    <RowsetSupportsAppendOnly>0</RowsetSupportsAppendOnly>
    <UseLevelZeroOledbInterfacesOnly>0</UseLevelZeroOledbInterfacesOnly>
    <RowsetUpdatability>1</RowsetUpdatability>
    <AsynchronousRowsetProcessingSupport>0</AsynchronousRowsetProcessingSupport>
    <DataSourceUnicodeLocaleId>0</DataSourceUnicodeLocaleId>
    <DataSourceUnicodeComparisonStyle>0</DataSourceUnicodeComparisonStyle>
    <DataSourceCollationComparisonFlags>0</DataSourceCollationComparisonFlags>
    <DataSourceCharacterset></DataSourceCharacterset>
    <DataSourceSortOrder></DataSourceSortOrder>
    <DataSourceNullCollationOrder>4</DataSourceNullCollationOrder>
    <CurrentDbCollationSameAsDefaultRemoteDbCollation>0</CurrentDbCollationSameAsDefaultRemoteDbCollation>
    <UnicodeLiteralSupport>0</UnicodeLiteralSupport>
    <UnicodeLiteralPrefix></UnicodeLiteralPrefix>
    <UnicodeLiteralSuffix></UnicodeLiteralSuffix>
    <DateLiteralPrefix></DateLiteralPrefix>
    <DateLiteralSuffix></DateLiteralSuffix>
    <ObjectNameConstructionFlags>54</ObjectNameConstructionFlags>
    <SchemaSeparator>.</SchemaSeparator>
    <CatalogSeparator>.</CatalogSeparator>
    <QuoteSeparator>"</QuoteSeparator>
    <BitRemoting>0</BitRemoting>
    <UnicodeLiterals>0</UnicodeLiterals>
    <ProviderOledbVersion>131072</ProviderOledbVersion>
    <HalloweenProtectionNeeded>1</HalloweenProtectionNeeded>
    <RowsetUsableAcrossThreads>0</RowsetUsableAcrossThreads>
    <ObjectNameIsSinglePart>0</ObjectNameIsSinglePart>
    <Cardinality>-1</Cardinality>
    <BookmarkSupport>0</BookmarkSupport>
    <BookmarksReusable>0</BookmarksReusable>
    <TableFlags>0</TableFlags>
</ProviderCapabilitiesAndSettings>
```

and here the details of the column in the filter:

```
DBCOLUMNINFO>
        <pwszName>z_PO</pwszName>
        <pTypeInfo>0x0000000000000000</pTypeInfo>
        <iOrdinal>53</iOrdinal>
        <dwFlags>120</dwFlags>
        <ulColumnSize>10</ulColumnSize>
        <wType>129</wType>
        <bPrecision>255</bPrecision>
        <bScale>255</bScale>
        <DBID>
            <eKind>DBKIND_NAME</eKind>
            <uName.pwszName>z_PO</uName.pwszName>
        </DBID>
    </DBCOLUMNINFO>
```

As a FYI, the context is wrapping the `openquery`, joined with local data, into a SQL Server view, which is the only thing users would see - from there, they can apply any filter (`WHERE`) within PowerQuery (XL) or PowerBI. A way to circumvent the lack of DirectQuery support through ODBC.

Comment: for what I understand, the server does exactly as instructed in case a) and case b). What seems to be the problem?

Comment: @access_granted I was under the impression the query optimizer would take the where clause, even if defined outside the remote sql, and send it to the linked server... It seems it does evaluate and can push scalar functions e.g. count(*) but not a where clause. Anyone to confirm or prove me wrong ?